# Setting variable to default value

Tags: scala

There's a class that uses an `ArrayBuffer` and I don't really care what is the value of the first element. In C# there's `default` keyword that returns `null` for reference types and default value (e.g. 0 for `int`) for value types. How to achieve something similar in Scala? I don't want to use `Option` because then there would be boilerplate code to extract values.

Comment: why would there be boilerplate with options? i think youve misunderstood options as a monadic type?

Comment: Why store an element in an array if you don't care what its value is?

Comment: @stew I do care about the rest of the elements, just not about the first one. I'm implementing a binary heap and there's a neat trick to start array index from one to make the code simpler.

Comment: This might interest you: http://missingfaktor.blogspot.fr/2011/08/emulating-cs-default-keyword-in-scala.html

Comment: `boilerplate code to extract values` does not make sense to me. How is this `val x = Some(5)`  and then `x.get` boilerplate? `Option` is superior to `null` because it defines a value (or not). Whereas `null` could mean anything. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Comment: @KevinMeredith well, it's not much but `xs(i) < xs(j)` is better than `xs(i).get < xs(j).get` and `Option` will introduce extra memory usage and another layer of indirection so I think it's not proper to use it when *only one element* that never gets accessed could be `null`. It's there just to simplify integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myInt: Int = _
```

Keyword for default values is: `_`

Comment: you are going to have to make that a var, can't be a val.

Comment: I think this is a typical metaquestion: The answer might be correct but the whole approach at first glance seems rather odd.

Comment: @StefanKunze that's the approach recommended by Robert Sedgewick so there's nothing odd about it.

Comment: @synapse : You can only judge a concept within a certain context.